# Counting symmetric binary matrices with constant line-sum

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory

I'm trying to count, as the title suggests, symmetric matrices with entries $0$ or $1$ and constant line-sum $k$. ($0 \leq k \leq n$). If you start listing the number of these on a table you'll get a triangle, $T(n,k)$ like this:
\begin{array}{c} \text{degree}\; \backslash \text{line-sum} 
       & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \dots  & \text{Sum}\\ \hline
0      & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &        & 1 \\
1      & 1 & 1 &   &   &   &   &        & 2 \\
2      & 1 & 2 & 1 &   &   &   &        & 4 \\ 
3      & 1 & 4 & 4 & 1 &   &   &        & 10\\
4      & 1 & 10& 18& 10& 1 &   &        & 40\\
5      & 1 & 26& ? & ? & 26& 1 &        & ? \\
\vdots &   &   &   &   &   &   & \ddots \end{array}

The column $T(n, 1)$ corresponds to the number of $n \times n$ symmetric permutation matrices ([A00085](http://oeis.org/A000085)). In general $T(n,k) = T(n, n-k)$ since, if we  have an element of $T(n, k)$ we can send $1 \mapsto 0$ and $0 \mapsto 1$, and have a corresponding element of $T(n, n-k)$.

$T(n, k)$ is equivalent to the number of $n$-vertex graphs with degree $k$ at every vertex (including loops).  A related question is: how many edges does this graph have?

I'm looking for a closed, or recursive formula for $T(n, k)$ because I've been struggling for a while on this.

Comment: see the paper of Musiker and Odama here https://www.mtholyoke.edu/courses/gcobb/REU_MCMC/papers.html

Comment: @deinst Thanks for the reference!